# XPath Optional Fields

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to write an XPATH expression which will handle optional elements in the following way: If the element is found, return the element, if its not found, return an empty value (or some constant would be fine also)

Example XML with optional element "address":

```
<account><name>Foobar</name><address>34 State St</address></account>
<account><name>Simpson</name></account>
<account><name>Cole</name><address>45 Main St</address></account>
```

Would need to return:

```
"34 State St",,"45 Main St"
or
"34 State St",constant,"45 Main St"
```

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 2.0 it's easy using `if`:

```
account/(if (address) then string(address) else '')
```

But in XPath 1.0 it's not possible in a single expression, since XPath 1.0 has no concept of ordered sequences of atomic values - it can only select sets of nodes.  You could extract the set of `account` elements using an XPath 1.0 expression but you would then need to iterate over that set of nodes in your host environment and look up the `address` for each one separately.

Comment: @MatthiasMüller that takes care of the if-then-else but doesn't help with the fundamental issue that there's no atomic sequences in XPath 1.0 and no way to do the sequence comprehension at the XPath level.